# AN additional $30,000 in income

Tags: indefinite-articles

I've found a phrase "**an** additional $30,000 in income" in a government document. Is the article **an** correct there and why?

Comment: Impossible to tell for sure without the context.  What document?

Comment: Yes, the use of the article "an" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

> If there is an adjective or an adverb-adjective combination before the
>   noun, A(AN) should agree with the first sound in the adjective or the
>   adverb-adjective combination.
>
> Examples:
>
> - He is an excellent teacher.
> - I saw a really beautiful eagle
>     at the zoo.

[Source](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm).

Comment: $30,000 treated as singular?

Comment: Oh, I didn't get the specific issue.  [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days) question may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, the amount is linguistically singular, because there's only one "additional" amount.  (Would still be singular for "amazing" or "fantastic", etc.)