# A + plural? Please help

Tags: articles

I have come across this sentence in a CNN report. 
"We can't smell them because we have a measly five million sensors in our noses, but dogs have up to 300 million sensors in their noses."

"...a measly five million sensors..." ?

When can we use the article "a" before a plural noun? Could this be a mistake?

Comment: This question has already been asked on stackexchange, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days.

Comment: The duplicate mentioned has good answers to this OP's question.