# Verb - agreement dilemma - 'first-two days'

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, expression-choice, indefinite-articles

I am having some trouble coming up with a natural-sounding expression whilst still ensuring conformity to the rule of Subject-verb agreement. At the centre of my concern is the phrase "first-two days" when strictly used with a dummy subject:

1) It ***was*** ***a*** tough first-two ***days***. (Not in agreement in number)

2) It ***was*** ***a*** tough  ***first-two-day***. (Unsure about the appropriateness of a hyphenated compound word)

3) They ***were*** tough first-two ***days***. (Grammatically sound but slightly jarring when spoken)

For the reasons in the brackets, none of the three is particularly desirable to me. But then again, my reasoning could be mistaken, so please shed some light on this.

Comment: Related: [Indefinite articles used with plural nouns: It was AN amazing TWO DAYS](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173)

Comment: Why are you hyphenating "first two"?

Comment: I thought that it might make more sense if it is a compound noun. But I was mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that **"two days" is a measure and measures are treated as singular.**

That is why your option 1 works as the subject, verb, and predicate *are* in agreement. However I do not believe it needs a hyphen

---

X was Y,  or X were Y ?

Can a singular be a plural?  Not often. X and Y are either both singular or both plural.

John was a champion, not John were champions.

If we choose "It" we must choose "was"

---

Next ... do we need an "a"?

If you chose a singular subject "it" you're going to compare it to something singular.

- *It was a X* : if X is a noun,
- *It was X*  : if X is an adjective

---

**Why can "two days" be singular?**

Well a "dozen" is a singular... it is a unit.

but, you might say "Two heads" are better than one. 
.... there "two x" is plural if X are thing(s), not a distance or measurement.

"Two days" as used in the predicate is singular because **"two days" is a measure**  (measuring a span of time).  That lets "two days" agree with "it".

~ a ~ measure.. Measures are treated as singular nouns so you would us an "a".  Other examples:

*4 hours is a long time to wait*

*The height difference between Mary and Jan ~is~ (not are) two inches.*

*Tommy is two heads taller than Lisa*  (haha, if you use 'heads' as a measure it changes things from the plural "two head" used as a subject!)

"tough" and "first" are simply adjectives referring to the span "it/two days".

With that explanation option 1) , the way we commonly hear it, is indeed grammatically sound - however the hyphen is not needed as "two days" is the measure, and 'first' is an adjective modifying the measure.

> It was a tough first two days

### ~

Option 3) of yours does also work.
It refers to "days" as individual time periods !
A plural "they" , the plural conjugated "to be" as "were" and "two days" here meaning two individual days.

> *They were tough first-two days.*

That would mean something ever so slightly different.. ~each~ day was tough.
Also, it may emphasize that the "day" as in the part of the day when the sun was up, were the tough parts rather than the 24 hour meaning.

The "first-two" as an adjective feels awkward in this plural and I'd be open for more input on the use of the hyphen.  Without a compound adjective this 3rd choice isn't awkward at all: 
"*They were tough first days.*" isn't awkward.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer, but may I point out you could write it much simpler: '2 days is a *span*' as you put it could perhaps be more accurately generalised as '2 days is a **measure** of time' -- and as you have already noted, it is a general convention that measures are treated as singular for most purposes: 1000 litres **was** the maximum this tanker could take/ 10 kilos **is** a lot to lose in just a week/ it **was** a hectic first 2 minutes (as in rugby union) -- *it's because measures are treated as singular that we choose **it was** here,* so OP needs 'it was' in this sentence!

Comment: @EnglishStudent thanks I know that my answer is a bit wordy and has superfluous parts.  I'll highlight what you suggest and use the term "measure"

Comment: I have similarly composed long answers myself while groping for some concept or otherwise struggling to explain my meaning. I tend to read it over many times *imagining myself as a third-party reader* and try to edit it to make perfect sense. Compared to that, it is too easy to look from outside upon another person's answer and see how I would improve it in your place! Thanks a lot. You are one of the most tolerant and understanding members at EL& U.

Comment: @EnglishStudent thank you for the compliment and understanding

Comment: You are most welcome. Everyone has their own personality, but I appreciate the many members like you with flexible, pleasant and helpful temperaments all the more because I have encountered many an intolerant or rigid mind, and at least one vitriolic tongue/pen on this website!

Comment: Very nice edit to update your answer! Strangely enough, some possibly odd sentences sound quite natural, as in "the first 2 days of the Great Rally Race were gruelling - they really took a lot out of us - **they were a tough first 2 days!**" This was pointed out by *Unrelated* in comments. 'They were' refers to the 2 days in the plural, but in the last sentence the use of the singular in '**a tough** first 2 days' introduces the concept of **measure** to complete an entirely natural-sounding construction: 'were' agrees with 'they'; 'a' with 'first 2 days'; and **they were a** is grammatical!

Comment: @EnglishStudent .. interesting!  That is why I said "not often" instead of 'always' in terms of subject predicate agreement. To be honest, this grammar begins to get "out of my league". I'm not really a grammarian. I believe that you can say things like "The elephants at the wildlife park were a marvel.", however I don't really understand why. Perhaps you can combine multiple things to one with "were" ? That perhaps is a separate question for someone to ask!

Comment: It becomes easy when (like me) you **don't** think grammar, but just think English. It is not complicated if we use our internal feel for the language. The *elephants* at the park *were* WHAT? They were marvelous. So what if I want to say marvel? Then I say "a marvel," because marvel is singular!

Answer (score 3):

Logical and grammatical number don't have to agree in English.  See for example [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1338/48571) and other questions under the [grammatical-number] tag.

A dummy subject is still a subject, and your "it" could stand for either a plural ("*my first two days at the company* were a tough first two days") or a singular ("*the induction course* was a tough first two days", "*that period of time* was a tough first two days").  I doubt you'd have a problem with the latter.  I'd drop the hyphen but otherwise go with this option -- "It was a tough first two days" seems perfectly natural spoken or written English (to these British ears)

The second example is (as you note yourself) a bit odd -- English doesn't have a compound noun "two-day" (though you do see it as an adjective), and it looks like that's what you're trying to use.

The third example also sounds unnatural.  A simple "the first two days were tough" would suffice if you wanted to stick with a plural throughout. "They were **a** tough first few days" is also perfectly sensible and keeps the S-V agreement.

"They were tough, the first two days" works, but is a little poetic to some ears (the structure makes me think of Larkin: [This be the verse](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/48419)).

Comment: Very nice.  My U.S. ears are fine with everything here. // Your last paragraph: For me, a slightly different version of this, "They were tough, those first two days," would be fine, and not poetic.

Comment: @aparente001 thank you. I've toned down that sentence given your additional viewpoint.

Comment: *They were **a** tough first two days* sounds fine to me, to go along with your point that the subject could be singular or plural. "They were tough, the first two days" works, sure, but no one would say that.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm my understanding. Is 'the first two days' singular or plural? Are you saying that it is a collective noun and a singular entity? Otherwise how could it take the indefinite article?