# Usage of article

Tags: articles

'Places near the equator have warm weather even in the cold season.'
Why is the article 'a' incorrect before 'warm weather'?

Comment: Your question is almost a copy of [“It was an awesome weather.” Is this sentence correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396176/it-was-an-awesome-weather-is-this-sentence-correct). Pity it was closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["It was an awesome weather." Is this sentence correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/396176/it-was-an-awesome-weather-is-this-sentence-correct)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I think Clare's answer is good but is it good SE policy to suggest "closed questions" as candidates?Bear in mind,  the question has one deletion vote in its favour so it *might* be deleted in the not too distant future.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A It depends on various factors. The answers etc at the candidate 'duplicate' are pretty comprehensive IMO. / This question is probably about general article usage rather than the finer points of using the indefinite article with noncount noun usages (She has a knowledge of French and German). If so' I'd say it shouldn't be on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth my bad, the linked question doesn't have a vote to delete. That it shouldn't be on EL&U is a fair assessment...but then again neither should 60% of the questions asked today but if the posted answers reflect EL&U's standards maybe questions shouldn't be closed as hurriedly as they sometimes are.

Comment: No; I'm  not saying that _the other_ question shouldn't be on ELU. I added the slash to try to signal an antecedent other than << the candidate 'duplicate' >>.

Answer (score 1):

Weather is a **mass noun**, which means it cannot take the indefinite article a/an alone.
The article "a" can only be attached to mass nouns when a quantifier specific to the noun is used.

> **A** *spell* of warm weather.

Other examples of mass nouns include air, grass and happiness.

Comment: This isn't a reliable rule, in either direction. The count-noncount differentiation hinges on the availability of using a numeral in the usage [CGEL]. Thus 'A subtle light flooded the clearing' (but not *'Three subtle lights flooded the clearing') / 'The state gave me a good education' (but not *'The state gave me two good educations'). 'I have an understanding of the principles involved' (but not *'I have two understandings ...') /  'I felt a strange warmth' (but not *'They felt two strange warmths') _all show noncount usages_.

Comment: 'He has an excellent knowledge of Italian' can't possibly be classed as a count usage according to the authors of CGEL. Take a look at the duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't really understand what you're trying to say, but mass nouns [can't](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-nouns/nouns-countable-and-uncountable) [take](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mass_noun) [the](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mass-noun) [indefinite](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/massnouns/) [article](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mass%20noun).

Comment: You're missing a vital piece of the explanation in the linked ODO article: 'usually '. See my answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight). Quirk et al (p 252) have 'It can be argued that some nouns, like weather, are neither count nor noncount, but share features belonging to both classes ...'.