# The syntax of 'a mere one stroke', 'a mere one game', etc

Tags: syntactic-analysis, indefinite-articles

> However, Bryson DeChambeau seized the lead by the end of Friday's second round and was **a mere one stroke** ahead of Reed and Erik van Rooyen.
>   (From [Bleacher Report](https://bleacherreport.com/articles/2877529-wgc-mexico-championship-2020-justin-thomas-leads-patrick-reed-entering-sunday))

It seems that **a** here is not a normal indefinite article because it doesn't seem to determine the head noun **stroke**. Note that **a mere** here means **merely**.

The question is how to parse **a mere one stroke**:

(1) [a mere] [one stroke]

(2) [[a mere] one] stroke

(3) a [mere [one stroke]]

(4) a [[mere one] stroke]

(5) [a [mere one]] stroke

---

Here's a similar example having the same construction:

> He played **a mere one game** in Miami, logging 12 special-teams snaps. ([Yahoo Sports](https://sports.yahoo.com/damien-williams-raheem-mostert-embrace-in-emotional-postgame-jersey-swap-044744477.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAACo9IvIMQZ2Xsj8HSEIw1QQ_MDRkwv1lmEcDchvKRclGK1-OwdrBkXtLGffnVfaW0wQAu_MjJRddVvF-phTNmg2cq7xden8Aa3Teo7IpIlIgIyWw0G2NNJzIeVpNbMiUgKpGUaj0y9vKWixszpxWYOBsfi42epNUcx0Te9E6ZRda))

Comment: If you think it sounds clumsy, I agree. '... a mere two strokes ...' is fine, or '... merely a single stroke ...'. // I'll go with 'a mere two strokes', which has the same structure but sounds (to my ears) more natural. 'Mere' is a strange beast, classified traditionally as an adjective, but recognised as a peripheral member of the class. 'He was a mere youth' means 'He was a member of the class 'youths', those immature, often unwise, largely unempowered, relatively unwealthy ...' ...You get the picture. 'Mere' attaches to 'youths' rather than 'he'.  So if I had to analyse the idiom, ...

Comment: I'd have to pull 'mere' out from 'a mere two strokes', comparing with '[merely] [a couple of strokes]'. Sentence adjective (!) + quasi-partitive/numeral substitute + noun? You can see why I just consider 'merely a couple of strokes',  'merely three inches' ...  (or 'a mere couple of strokes', 'a mere three inches' ...) an idiom.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think 'a mere one stroke' is clumsy. Nope. And I don't think 'a mere two strokes' is an idiom. In any case, it's not about 'a mere two strokes' or about 'mere' itself. In fact, you can replace 'mere' with 'meager' and get 'a meager one stroke', which I think has the same syntax.

Comment: "a mere two strokes" outperforms "a mere one stroke" in a Google search 35:1. And the second example is _merer_.  // Whatever; 'mere', 'meagre', 'paltry' ... refer to the measure (two strokes etc) not the noun per se (stroke/s) but need context to be used ('a mere gingko'??? 'a mere planetoid'??? (not if it hits the Earth). 'Leading by a mere 17 runs' (cricket) but not 'leading by a mere 17 goals'. So 'mere' may 'attach' to say '2 runs' (and then the idiom is _led by_ 'a mere 2 runs', with the article), but 'mere' refers to a context also.

Comment: Note that the indefinite article can be used with adjectives like "amazing" or "great" + a numeral + a plural noun, discussed in this question: [Indefinite articles used with plural nouns: It was AN amazing TWO DAYS](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days)

Comment: @herisson But 'stroke' or 'game' in the OP is not a plural noun.

Comment: If *a mere* means *merely*, then *a mere* is an adverbial. [*a mere*] [*one stoke*]; [*only*] [*one stroke*]

Comment: @TinfoilHat If _a mere_ is an adverbial, how could an adverbial such as _a mere_ or _only_ modify the nominal _one stroke_?

Comment: Are you concerned about adverbs modifying nouns? That's [a whole big thing](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/PaynHuddPull.pdf). It's also not a problem. If you can get past that, the rest is easy.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I'm not "concerned" about that. I'm open to adverbs modifying nouns and NPs. It's just that I don't think this is one of those cases. In fact, I remember reading the paper like a year ago. If memory serves, that paper doesn't say anything about adverbs like _merely_ in _merely one stroke_ modifying the nominal _one stroke_. What _merely_ modifies is _one_. Hence the ungrammatical *_a merely stroke_ and *_merely strokes_.

Answer (score 2):

Updated to reflect discussion in comments . . .

I would not assume that *a mere* means the same thing as *merely* just because you can swap one in for the other here. But when *a mere* appears before a noun modified by a cardinal number, you can remove it. So I would parse *a mere one stroke* like this:

> [*a mere*] [*one stroke*]

What you want to call these things is between you and your grammarian. Meanwhile, let's look at some examples:

> *He was a mere one stroke ahead.*
>   *He was one stroke ahead.*
>   *He was a mere five strokes ahead.*
>   *He was five strokes ahead.*

Again, it's the **cardinal numbers** that are key here:

> *He was a mere child.*
>  
>   **He was child.* (incorrect)
>   *The candy was a mere penny.*
>   **The candy was penny.* (incorrect)
>   *The candy was a mere **one** cent.*
>   *The candy was **one** cent.*
>   *The candy was a mere **ten** cents.*
>   *The candy was **ten** cents.*

Linguists Adele E. Goldberg and Laura A. Michaelis offer this explanation:

> There exists one systematic exception to the restriction barring the
>   indefinite article from combining with a cardinal number. The
>   indefinite article *can* precede 1-ONE and other cardinal
>   numbers when the cardinal is preceded by an adjectival modifier:
>
> ```
> Butterfat content for sherbet might be a mere one percent or less. (*a one percent)
> a scant one week after he died (*a one week)
> There will be a lucky one contestant randomly brought back in a pre‐match. (*a one contestant)
> TV star Kirstie Alley lost a whopping 30 pounds. (*a 30 pounds)
> The site has grown to a staggering 60 million members. (*a 60 million members)
> ```
>
> We postulate that the indefinite determiner is  required in this
>   context because the cardinal number is no longer serving as a
>   determiner, but rather as a modifier.
>  <sub>Source: [One Among
>   Many: Anaphoric One and Its Relationship With Numeral
>   One](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/cogs.12339)</sub>

In simplistic terms: If you put an adjectival modifier in front of your cardinal, your cardinal changes from a determiner to a modifier, and you still need a determiner. Put another way, the indefinite article + adjective is a package deal: [*a mere*]. No adjective, no article:

> **He was a five strokes ahead.* (incorrect)

Researcher Stephanie Solt further examines the modified cardinal construction and notes, among other things, that there are . . .

> . . . two types of the modified cardinal construction, showing that
>   both involve  coercion of the modified element to the semantic type of
>   a singular noun, an analysis that suggests an  explanation for the
>   obligatory occurrence of the indefinite article *a*.
>  <sub>Source:
>   [Two Types of Modified
>   Cardinals](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267373402_Two_Types_of_Modified_Cardinals)</sub>

Here are some examples:

> Type 1—adjective modifies **noun phrase** (quality):
>   *It was a long **five miles**.*
>
> Type 2—adjective modifies **cardinal number** (quantity):
>   *It was a mere **five** strokes.*

In both cases though, you can remove the indefinite article and the adjective, and if you remove one, you must remove the other. I'll let the linguists continue to postulate beyond that.

Comment: +1 for the paper citations. I'll definitely be taking a look at them when I get the time.

Comment: Granted, _a mere_ can be replaced with _merely_ or _only_, but I think not all 'a/an + adjective' constructions can be replaced with adverbs, can they? What adverbs can substitute for _a scant_, _a lucky_, _a whopping_, _a staggering_, etc. in the examples shown in your answer?

Comment: Hm. Syntactically, they can all be swapped for certain adverbs. But, true, they can't all be swapped while retaining the meaning. The meaningful swap seems to be coincidental to certain adjectives that have corresponding degree adverbs (or synonyms): _**a scant** one week_ --> _**barely/hardly** one week_.  _**an approximate** 30 pounds_ --> _**approximately/about** 30 pounds_. _**a near** 60 million members_ --> _**nearly/almost** 60 million members_.

Comment: As per the second paper, Type 1 is not possible for the adverb swapping at all. Type 2 is only partially possible. So maybe you should edit the last sentence of your answer.

Comment: I am wondering if I should take out the adverb swapping examples altogether. Now that I think about it, saying *a mere* means *merely* is a bit of red herring; their syntactic swapability does not prove they are semantically equivalent.

Comment: More importantly, the syntactic swapability argument hinges on the apparently false semantic equivalence claim. Without the former even the parsing [a mere] [one stroke] itself is questionable.

Comment: On page 243 of Goldberg are such examples as "However, after seeing the ample size of the taco, **a mere one** was sufficient." These examples might suggest that we parse the NP as (5). What do you think?

Comment: That's a fused-head type of *one*? Reading CGEL now on cardinal numbers and when they go from determiners to modifiers.

Comment: CGEL doesn't touch on the particular construction at issue here, but you'll have to first determine how to parse the construction and only then can you identify the correct fused head. If you choose (5), for example, the fused head is not 'one' but 'a mere one'.

Comment: I don't think (5) is relevant here, unless we want to get into a whole different discussion about how bare cardinals are functioning. We don't have a bare cardinal; head noun *stroke* follows cardinal *one*. What we know: the presence of indefinite article *a* is licensed by the intervening adjective (e.g. *mere*). No adjective, no article. So we can at least parse this as a package deal: [*a mere*].

Comment: @JK2: I've update the answer -- not sure how far it gets us.

Comment: If the intervening adjective licensed the indefinite article, you would have an independent unit comprising only the two. But you don't. You can't remove the cardinal number 'one': "However, after seeing the ample size of the taco, **a mere** was sufficient" is ungrammatical; "...was **a mere stroke** ahead of Reed and Erik van Rooyen" has a different meaning altogether. So I'd say it's not the adjective itself but the 'adjective + cardinal number' combo that licenses the indefinite article. Hence (5).

Answer (score 1):

Note that "a mere two strokes" would be equally valid (to most people), so "a" is not directly connected to "one stroke".  Best guess is that "a" modifies "mere", and pretty much stops there.  (Note that one could equally validly use "a paltry" or some similar construction.)

And "a mere" is clearly modifying "one stroke", vs "one", since "one stroke" could be replaced by simply "stroke" (or, in another venue, "goal" or even "fish")

This is a mushy area of English syntax, tied up in idiom.  Extending my guess, idiomatic usages such as this treat "mere" as a sort of agglomerator, somehow carrying a prepositional effect similar to "pair of".

Consider "An astounding 800 people are in line to hear the governor speak."  One wouldn't say "... is in line ...", nor would one say "A 800 people are in line ..."  In this example "astounding" is short for "astounding crowd of", or some such, even though there's no hint of "simple" word elision.

Comment: You seem to be going for syntax (1). I'm sure your first paragraph is fine. But I'm not so sure about your second. True, replacing "one stroke" with "stroke" doesn't affect the grammaticality of the phrase, but it does affect the meaning, doesn't it? So I'm not sure the one with only "stroke" has the same syntax. Also, if "a mere two strokes" has the same syntax as "a mere one stroke" as suggested in your first paragraph, then "two strokes" should also be able to be replaced by simply "strokes", but it can't. (*_...was a mere strokes ahead of Reed and Erik van Rooyen._)

Comment: I think my first comment is still valid even after you add the third and fourth paragraphs.

Comment: Re the ellipsis (not 'elision') analysis, what's the ellipted phrase in "a mere __________ one stroke" corresponding to "pair of" or "crowd of"?

Comment: @JK2 - "margin of"

Comment: But _a mere margin of two strokes_ is treated as singular, whereas _a mere two strokes_ as plural. If the latter is formed from ellipsis of _margin of_, why are they treated differently in number?

Comment: @JK2 No, 'A mere two strokes is not a decisive lead' (a singular length) not  'A mere two strokes are not a decisive lead'. In line with '3 dollars is a trifling amount for a ticket'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's a little misleading. Your singular treatment has nothing to do with the 'a mere' construction. You'd still prefer 'Two strokes is not a decisive lead' over 'Two strokes are not a decisive lead'. Since 'stroke' is tricky, let's make it 'player'. You can say 'A mere two players have scored all the goals in the last five games' but not 'A mere two players has scored all the goals in the last five games'. Note that the syntax of 'a mere two players' is the same as that of 'a mere two strokes' and of 'a mere one stroke'.

Answer (score 1):

> Bryson DeChambeau […] was a mere one stroke ahead of Reed

As is pointed out above, this is essentially no different from a paltry/slim/threatening, etc., one or two strokes ahead of Reed in which **mere** is an adjective.

"**One or two strokes**" is an interesting noun phrase (number + noun).  Compare:

*“The total was **a mere** five goals/gallons/miles/dollars/metres, etc short of what was required.*” or *"Five gallons was enough to fill the tank."*

I assume the context of the question is golf, and in golf, a stroke is a unit of measurement and thus, when combined with a number, is treated as a singular amount comprised of that number and unit of measurement.

Thus
Bryson DeChambeau […] was a mere [one stroke] ahead of Reed.

("ahead of Read" is adjectival.)

Comment: The construction is not limited to a unit of measurement.