# "Two additional days" but "an additional two weeks"

Tags: grammar, countable-nouns, adjective-position

[[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&year_end=2019&content=two+additional+days%2Can+additional+two+days%2Ctwo+additional+weeks%2Can+additional+two+weeks&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20additional%20days%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20additional%20two%20days%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20additional%20weeks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20additional%20two%20weeks%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctwo%20additional%20days%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20additional%20two%20days%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20additional%20weeks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20additional%20two%20weeks%3B%2Cc0)][image]
I'd like to know what are the grammatical differences between both structures, as well as one or the other predominates for days and weeks.
[image]

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days

Comment: I wonder if this has to do with preserving the construction "two weeks notice." One would say "an additional two weeks notice" but not "two additional weeks notice."

Comment: If you swap 'three' for 'two' in all these phrases, you get graphs that are far closer. And 'an additional four days' has outperformed 'four additional days' on occasion.

Comment: @d_b For me it's uncountable, either _two weeks' notice_ or _two-week notice_. Yet I just found _two-weeks' notice_ https://www.wordreference.com/definition/notice

Comment: @EdwinAshworth any reason why _further_ behaves differently? https://i.imgur.com/v0bmvO1.jpeg

Comment: It's simple writer's choice.  Which "sounds" best depends on other words in the context.